# Show embedded images in Mac Word

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, office-for-mac

I have a client who insists on sending me screenshots as images embedded in MS Word docx files.  I can view these images by opening the documents in Word on my Windows machine but on any Mac machines there is just an empty box where the image should be.  I ran the document through several online document viewers including google docs and the only one that could open it was viewdocumentsonline.  It's a stop gap solution as I really need to be able to handle these files locally.

Per suggestions in a similar question, I downloaded the Unarchiver and used it to extract the docx files.  Each have a image.wmf file that is the only thing that could possibly be the image, but when I open them with the trial version of WMF Converter Pro they just show up as black boxes in there as well.  The fact that VDO and MS Word on Windows shows the images tells me there has to be some way of viewing them.  Or maybe there is a setting in Mac Word that will help me fix this extremely annoying problem?

Comment: The fact that both Word for Mac and WMF Converter Pro (which I'm assuming is running on Mac as well) both display the same invalid output, means there something system-wide at fault. My guess is that since WMF uses GDI which is not available on Mac, the rendering of the image simply doesn't work. The easiest solution: suggest your client to embed the images in a different format such as PNG instead :)

Comment: A couple of test documents created here on windows word with wmf e and emus opened ok on my installation of mac word 2011 (on mountain lion). I also checked the XML in the .docx. So I wonder whether it is all documents with .wmf s that fail, or just some ( e.g. Can you create your own such document as a test?)